# how long length is Parse server sessionToken, masterKey safe?

Tags: parse-platform

What's generally using length of token and masterKey?
`sessionToken`'s length is 32. Is this safe? Can I change it?

I know the parse-server developers are genius. But my knowledge is continuing to ask 'is this safe?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***What's generally using length of token and masterKey?***

There is not an answer, but you can set length to 40, random from a-zA-Z0-9 as same as Parse.com.

***sessionToken's length is 32. Is this safe?***

Each character of parse-server is 0-9a-f (hex). There are 16 ^ 32 (about 3 * 10 ^ 38) possible token. If you have 100,000,000 (10^8) users and each user have 3 sessions(total 3*10^8 sesssions). Possibility of random a token to fit one session is about 3*10^8 / 3* 10 ^ 38 = 1/10^30

So you may guess 10^30 times to fit "one" of sessions. I think is enough.

***Can I change it?***

Yes, you can modify the source code to fit what you want. Or make a PR for a config to determine how token generate. Token is been generated by [cryptoUtils.newToken()](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/blob/master/src/cryptoUtils.js).